# EntityQuery PHP issue when assigning the query to a variable

Tags: 8, database

I am very confused about this behavior of EntityQuery, or maybe I am just missing something basic about PHP.

Here is the query I am working with:

```
$entity_query_points1 = \Drupal::entityQuery($entity_type_id)
  ->condition($entity_type->getKey('bundle'), $entity_type_bundle)
  ->condition($entity_type->getKey('uid'), $uid)
  ->condition('field_int_points', 1, '=');
return $entity_query_points1;
```

This is fine.

But if this query returns no results, I wanted to immediately execute another query.  So I made a `switch` statement and wrote code like this:

```
$entity_query_points1 = \Drupal::entityQuery($entity_type_id)
  ->condition($entity_type->getKey('bundle'), $entity_type_bundle)
  ->condition($entity_type->getKey('uid'), $uid)
  ->condition('field_int_points', 1, '=');
$entity_query = $entity_query_points1;
$count = $entity_query->count()->execute();
if ($count >= 1) {
  return $entity_query_points1;
}
```

This fails with a WSOD (I am using this code with the JSON:API Resources module):

```
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\jsonapi_resources\Resource\EntityQueryResourceBase::loadResourceObjectsByEntityIds() must be of the type array, string given, called in /app/web/modules/contrib/jsonapi_resources/src/Resource/EntityQueryResourceBase.php on line 97 in Drupal\jsonapi_resources\Resource\EntityQueryResourceBase->loadResourceObjectsByEntityIds() (line 125 of modules/contrib/jsonapi_resources/src/Resource/EntityQueryResourceBase.php).
```

If I use the following code, it works (query resolved correctly, no WSOD):

```
$entity_query_points1 = \Drupal::entityQuery($entity_type_id)
  ->condition($entity_type->getKey('bundle'), $entity_type_bundle)
  ->condition($entity_type->getKey('uid'), $uid)
  ->condition('field_int_points', 1, '=');
$entity_query = $entity_query_points1;
$count = $entity_query->count()->execute();
if ($count >= 1) {
  $entity_query_score1 = \Drupal::entityQuery($entity_type_id)
    ->condition($entity_type->getKey('bundle'), $entity_type_bundle)
    ->condition($entity_type->getKey('uid'), $uid)
    ->condition('field_int_points', 1, '=');
  return $entity_query_points1;
}
```

But... why?  I executed the count on `$entity_query`, but I have to redefine `$entity_query_score1` to return the query as expected.  I know having to redefine the query means I have screwed up somehow, but I don't know what my mistake is.

Comment: Curious to see what happens if you use `$entity_query = clone $entity_query_points1;` because objects might behave different I think

Comment: @baikho Adding `clone` works; then I no longer need to redefine the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects work differently than regular variables in PHP. They are "assigned by reference", generally speaking. The [Objects and References](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) page in the PHP manual goes into some detail about this. Basically, your `=` is not working as you expect. `$entity_query` and `$entity_query_points1` are "the same object".

As noted by @baikho in the comments, you'll need to use `clone` to achieve what you're trying to do.

```
$entity_query = clone $entity_query_points1;
```